# Pandas resample function dynamically

Tags: dataframe, resampling

I have some logged data where there is a big change in the beginning and smaller later in the dataset.

I have created a timedelta dataframe and now I would like to have high resolution in the beginning and larger later e.g. a delta t step size like:
`deltaT = 0.001 + (1-exp(-t/10))*0.5`
here t is the current time